# Insert error : from R to Access DB

Tags: r, dataframe, rodbc

Using the below code to insert data from R to Access DB

```
sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO test(test1,test2,test3) 
          VALUES('",df1$test1,"','",df1$test2,"','",df1$test2,"',)")
appendRecords <- lapply(sql, function(x) sqlQuery(channel, x))
```

Column Test1 has text data that contain special character like (' " ,) due that I am getting the following error

```
[1] "42000 -3100 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error 
(missing operator) in query expression '\\\\.\\ROOT\\XXXX' \\n  \\n...''."
```

Data in column 
     (a'\\.\ROOT\XXXX' \n  \n...''.)

How to fix that issue??

Comment: Looks like you have an extra comma after the last value. `sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO test(test1,test2,test3) VALUES('",df1$test1,"','",df1$test2,"','",df1$test2,"')")`, And also you might want to use `sqlUpdate` instead of `sqlQuery`, since you have nothing to fetch here.

Comment: I'm able insert other values. when the data contain special character it ignores that record

Comment: Is `'\\.\ROOT\XXXX'` the original string in your data frame? Might be worthwhile to search for R encoding/decoding strings?

Comment: Yes, 20 % of my data will have Special character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to find a permanent solution.
so i have made temporary solution, Hope this helps all.

```
  df1$test1 = gsub("'", "", as.character(df1$test1)) # this remove '.
```

After that Inserting it into DB.